# Errors with ATFTPD: Unterminated quoted string

Tags: apt, software-center, dpkg

After upgrading Ubuntu from 11.04 to 11.10 (32bits) I'm having trouble with ATFTPD:

Anytime I'm starting atftpd I'm getting this error:

```
/etc/default/atftpd: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Anytime I'm trying to install/remove any package (`apt-get` or Ubuntu Software Center) I'm getting this error:

```
Setting up atftpd (0.7.dfsg-10) ...

/etc/default/atftpd: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

dpkg: error processing atftpd (--configure):

subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2

Errors were encountered while processing:

atftpd

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

First try

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

If that fails, try to remove the package

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all atftpd
```

If that fails, manually remove

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo rm -f atftpd.*
```

Then

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq atftpd
```